# Incorporating check boxes and radio buttons, visual basic

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm writing a program to calculate internet charges.  Three packages, A, B, and C to choose from costing $9.95(10 hours; $2/hour extra), $14.95(15 hours; $1/hour extra) and $19.95(unlimited).

Here is the code I have written for input from masked text boxes (for just one case).  I would like to simplify by using check boxes and radio buttons but I have never used them before.  Any hints or tips?

```
Case "A"
                If hours < 10 And nonprofit.ToUpper = "Y" Then
                    lstOutput.Items.Add("Total Cost is " & FormatCurrency(9.95 * 0.8))
                    'package A with nonprofit status, under limit
                ElseIf hours < 10 And nonprofit.ToUpper = "N" Then
                    lstOutput.Items.Add("Total Cost is " & FormatCurrency(9.95))
                    'package A without nonprofit status, under limit
                ElseIf hours > 10 And nonprofit.ToUpper = "Y" Then
                    lstOutput.Items.Add("Total Cost is " & FormatCurrency((9.95 + _
                        (hours - 10) * 2) * 0.8))
                    'package A with nonprofit status, over limit
                ElseIf hours > 10 And nonprofit.ToUpper = "N" Then
                    lstOutput.Items.Add("Total Cost is " & FormatCurrency(9.95 + _
                        (hours - 10) * 2))
                    'package A without nonprofit status, over limit
                End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm not understanding your question - it should be as simple as modifying your code to include a checkbox, such as for nonprofit, then when you process:

```
Dim nonprofit As Boolean = NonProfit_CB.Checked
```

Then checked if nonprofit is true(instead of checking for Y/N):

```
If nonprofit = True Then
```

RadioButtons are basically the same as CheckBoxes.  Also if you want to group radio buttons together, so only one of the group can be selected, place them in a Group Box...